# Is it possible to always get the most recent imagery with the Google Street View API?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, maps, google-street-view

I'm working on a site that shows street view panoramas of parcels using the Google Maps API. I would like to always show the **most recent** imagery for these parcels, ideally programmatically, but I can't find a way to do so in the API. Is it possible to do set a preference that tells the API that you always want the most recent imagery? Failing that, is there a way to get all of the matching imagery and manually pick the most recent one?

Comment: any luck with this?

Comment: No, I've given up for now.